# StreamSubscription in initState has results when entering page the second time

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with the below code. Sorry for posting so much, but I hope that it will help solve the problem.

So what I need to do is get users that left messages in a chat room. If these users changed their profile picture, I want to have the updated pic. So I save their ids in `chatUsers` when they interact with the chat room.

Then I create a list of lists with ten ids in each list and use `whereIn` to create streams for each of the lists. These streams are then added to a `StreamZip` as seen below.

When listening to the streams, I add each value to `chatUsersList`. `chatUsersList` is checked for length before rendering the widgets. This is why it's confusing. Why does the page render if `chatUsersList` is empty?

My problem is that when I first install the app, when entering the chat for the FIRST time, the widgets are rendered even though `chatUsersList` is empty, so the user images are returned as a default image in `getImageUrl()`.
`Everything works fine the second time the chat page is accessed.` I don't know why and what to do.

```
List chatUsersList = [];
StreamSubscription chatUsers;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chatUsers').get().then((snap) {
  var _chunks = [];
  List<Stream<dynamic>> _streams = [];

  final documents =
      snap.docs.map((doc) => UserModel.fromFirestore(doc)).toList();

  final count = 10;

  for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i += count) {
    _chunks.add(
      documents.sublist(
        i,
        i + count > documents.length ? documents.length : i + count,
      ),
    );
  }

  final uids = _chunks.map((x) => x.map((y) => y.id).toList()).toList();

  for (var i = 0; i < uids.length; i++) {
    Stream stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('uid', whereIn: uids[i])
        .snapshots();
    _streams.add(stream);
  }

  StreamZip myStreams = StreamZip(_streams);

  chatUsers = myStreams.asBroadcastStream().listen((value) {
    final d = value.toList();
    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
      var users = d[i].docs.map((u) => UserModel.fromFirestore(u)).toList();
      setState(() {
        chatUsersList = [...chatUsersList, ...users];
      });
    }
  });
});

focusNode.addListener(onFocusChange);
listScrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);

isLoading = false;
isShowSticker = false;
imageUrl = '';

readLocal();
}

  @override
  void dispose() {
    chatUsers.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

This is the function I use to retrieve the user's pic:

```
  getImageUrl(doc) {
    final uid = doc['idFrom'];
    final find = chatUsersList.firstWhere((element) => element.uid == uid,
        orElse: () => null);
    if (find != null) {
      return find.smallPhotoURL != null ? find.smallPhotoURL : find.photoURL;
    }
    return "https://...defaultImage.png";
  }
```

Then in the build I check if chatUsersList is populated.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return chatUsersList.length > 0
    ? WillPopScope(...
: Container();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the chatUsersList is accessed before it is available or checked in your build context.

You can use `FutureBuilder`widget. In the [Official Fluter Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) you have more information about how to use it with some interactive examples.

Then use an If statement to make sure the data is there and throw a [CircularProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html).

Something like this:

```dart
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
```